# Mapbox style not updating

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-studio

I am not sure why but the mapbox style is not updating or showing properly in the client side map?   Also how come I am not able to make labels show from my data set and can only have them show using the place labels or point of interest labels?

[Production Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8uFI.png)

[Style as published in studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3UF6.png)

Comment: Your second "Also..." is a totally different question and should be asked separately.

Answer (score 1):

It can often take quite a while for style changes to trickle through various layers of caching. Using the `/draft` URL can help. If all else fails, publish the style as a new style ID, and use that.